Copy Row of Cells to Another Sheet for Repeated Use
Context: I am making an Excel workbook where others can open it and enter 3 separate values in 3 cells, in a row (see below), with their initials attached to it.



List
Values




x
value input1


y
value input2


z
value input3


initials
value initials



Problem: Ideally, I would have a VBA button which, once the user presses the button, it will copy the data into another sheet or some hidden cells such that when the next person opens the spreadsheet, they will not be able to see the previous person's data entry. For each button press, it would ideally enter the row of data into a separate row such that it does not overwrite the previous person's data. So if three people were to enter the values above and press the button, there would be three rows from the three people. I hope this makes sense.
I have tried a few solutions from stackoverflow and stackexchange but they have not completed the full task.
I was able to find one solution where the data did copy into a separate sheet and placed the data underneath pre-entered list of initials (matching the initials entered to what was stored in the separate sheet) but only for a single cell of data. This is different to what I have described above but attempted it this way around to see if I could get it to work. That solution: Excel vba button to paste data from one cell into another cell using date criteria

This code records the specified range on the Reg sheet as a row with added the date/time when occured.
Sub data_copier()

Set inp_range = Worksheets("base").Range("B2:B5")  'the name of the input sheet

Set reg_sheet = Worksheets("Reg")    ' the name of the backup sheet

last_row = reg_sheet.Cells(reg_sheet.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If last_row <> 1 Then
  last_row = last_row + 1
End If
reg_sheet.Range(reg_sheet.Cells(last_row, 1), reg_sheet.Cells(last_row, 4)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(inp_range)
inp_range.Clear
reg_sheet.Cells(last_row, 5) = Now

End Sub

Variance
if there are no other data on the Reg sheet then use to define last_row like this:
last_row = reg_sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

this resolve if not all the cells are filled in the input range.

Thank you for this, it is very helpful. When the code takes the data and inputs it into the next sheet, the initials aren't deleted and it displays a "#N/A" in the second sheet. Is there a way around this? Apologies, I incorrectly wrote that the initials were a value in my original question.

Is there a formula which creates the initials? Or an event function to the sheet?

The user will enter their initials manually into the cell e.g. B5, but this will be text rather than a number. So all four cells of data the user inputs will be them typing it in. There are no formulae or event functions in the sheet.

Probably the inp_range size is not correct. It must be the same size of cells as in the assignment command line. In our case 4.

That has fixed the problem, I was using the old range from the answer I linked in my post. Thank you for that. I have not changed anything in the code but it now does not add data entry to new separate rows in sheet2.

Pls. post the code you use effectively in your question as code text now i cannot say further anything till that.

I have used the code you suggested in your answer but with different names for the sheets.

it can occur if x value is not set.

How do I set 'x' ? Apologies, I am a complete novice and trying to learn.
